# Is there any unique identifier for an application running on windows?

Tags: c#, desktop-application, uniqueidentifier, tracker

I am developing a desktop application, using C#, to track the applications which are running in windows. Is that any unique number for every application which is installed in windows?

I can get the handle number but the handle number is changed while reopening the application.

I need the unique identifier for every application installed in windows.

Comment: No, there isn't. You can make educated guesses using things like the MSI package GUID (assuming it was installed with MSI) or pathnames or hashing the exe contents but there's nothing guaranteed to be both unique and stable.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I guess the most reliable ID you'll be able to get is the exe file path. Don't try to map that to a number though.

Answer (score 0):

Use the WMI System.Management API.  I think you want the IdentifyingNumber which will give you a GUID for the product.

```
    ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Product");
    foreach (ManagementObject mo in mos.Get())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(mo["Name"]);
        foreach (PropertyData prop in mo.Properties)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", prop.Name, prop.Value);
        }
    }
```